# React.js Material UI - CardActionArea with flex display - children elements don't use full width

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Straight to the point - I've tried replacing `display` style parameter from `block` to `flex`, with `flexDirection: 'column'` for `CardActionArea` component. The reason for this was to make sure that `CardContent` has the same height for every `Card` in a row - which I achieved. However... `CardHeader` and `CardContent` fail to achieve `width: '100%'` after changing the `display`. The illustration below should clarify what I mean.

[image]
The following is the related code

**render**

```
<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardActionArea
    className={classes.cardActionArea}
    onClick={this.loadGroup}
  >
    <CardHeader
      avatar={
        <FolderIcon />
      }
      classes={{
        root: classes.header,
        title: classes.headerTitle,
        subheader: classes.headerSubheader
      }}
      title={this.state.group.name}
      subheader={this.renderModuleCount()}
    />
    <CardContent className={classes.content}>
      {this.renderContent()}
    </CardContent>
  </CardActionArea>
  <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
    <IconButton onClick={this.showDialog}>
      <DeleteIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </CardActions>
</Card>
```

**styles**

```
card: {
  width: '30%',
  margin: theme.spacing(1),
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
},
cardActionArea: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column'
},
header: {
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
  width: '100%',
},
headerTitle: {
  color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
},
headerSubheader: {
  color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
},
content: {
  flexGrow: 1,
},
```

I'm looking to see how I could resolve this. I couldn't find any `padding` or `margin` on `ButtonBase`, `CardActionArea` MUI components.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finnaly I found a solution. Style class `cardActionArea` needs to use the following:

```css
cardActionArea: {
  flexGrow: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  alignItems: 'stretch',
},
```

The result:
[image]